# How can fix the issue of Unsafe Header Settings for "Content-Length"

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an API that when I call for first I get this error, but when I refreshed the screen and so I got a response.

My request is :

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:shndz/constants.dart';

import '../model/get_sms_model.dart';

// model service is : GetSmsCode

class ServiceSendCode extends GetConnect implements GetxService {
  Map<String, String> authorizationh = {};
  Map<String, String> bodyMap = {};
  String phoneNumber = "";

  ServiceSendCode(this.phoneNumber);

  Future<GetSmsCode> postData(BuildContext context) async {
    bodyMap = {
      'phone_number': phoneNumber,
    };

    authorizationh = {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "content-length": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":
          "true", // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
          "Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,locale",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, OPTIONS"
    };

    var res = await post(config.loginUrl, bodyMap,
        headers: authorizationh);

    if (res!.statusCode == 401) {
      toastWarning(
          'Error',
          'Verification code just sent. Please try again in a few seconds',
          context,
          true);
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
    } else if (res!.statusCode == 200) {
      toastSuccess(
          'Send sms code', context, true);
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      Get.toNamed(Rverification);
    }

    return GetSmsCode.fromJson(res.body);
  }
}
```

Error is:

[image: How can fix the issue of Unsafe Header Settings for Content-Length]

I tried setting the header on my response for [content-length] but I got the same issue.

Comment: Adding CORS headers to a request as you show here will obviously have no effect! CORS headers are added by the server to the response.

Comment: @RichardHeap -> If you look carefully, I mentioned it below, sir

Answer (score -1):

**I found a way for prevent this error:**

1 - Add this header to your API  -> `'Accept': 'application/json'`.

2- Export web app from your source with command `flutter build web --web-renderer html --release`     .

3[important]- Open index.html from after export and add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />` on.

**Why number 3 is important because if we export a released Web App from our source after then possible not to show image assets very well or not show at all, so the point in number 3 helps me show all assets in my project after the release.
also, number 2 is important because not work if it isn't added to the header's request.**

**Cors is Required in web app [don't forget]: 

1- use the CORS header in the backend side [just web app or otherwise don't need it]

2- also use the CORS header on the Front side [just web app or otherwise don't need it]**

This method works for me, I hope, if you got this error, it solves your problems also.